# Border not visible

Tags: css, sass, styles

Why is the border not visible under the input field?

Also, the button goes over the Border and the border is continuous for the button next to it, but not for the input field.

[image: image of the result]

My CSS

```css
input,
button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  height: 60px;
  outline: 0;
}
input {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
button {
  width: 100px;
}
input:after {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
input:after,
button:after {
  transition: 200ms all ease;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "Select package.json";
}
button:after {
  content: "Upload";
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0;
}
input:hover:after,
button:hover:after {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the html and also check the given scss as i don't get the same output as yours. You have given the tag as sass, but it should be scss.

Comment: Note that input elements cannot have pseudo elements attached.

Answer (score -1):

I made some minor adjustments to  `.input, button` and added some border attributes to `input`.

```css
input,
    button {
        display: inline-flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 60px;
        outline: 0;
        line-height: 60px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    input {
        border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #afafaf;
        border-right: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #afafaf;
        border-left: 1px solid #afafaf;
        padding: 0 0 0 12px;
        
    }
    button {
        width: 100px;
    }
    input:after {
        border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }
    input:after,
    button:after {
        transition: 200ms all ease;
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
        border: 1px solid #afafaf;
        color: #252525;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        content: 'Select package.json';
    }
    button:after {
        content: 'Upload';
        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0;
    }
    input:hover:after,
    button:hover:after {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

```html
<input/><button></button>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what you did, not juste code.

Comment: In this case barely anything changed